# Dual GridView simultaneous and synchronized scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have an issue in an android app that so far I have not been able to come up with a solution for. There is probably something obvious that I am missing so maybe someone can suggest a good solution for me.

So basically I have two side by side GridViews in a horizontal layout. The left GridView is one column and the right GridView dynamically adapts the number of columns to fit the screen. Basically the left GridView is a programmatically populated row header column for the right GridView. I have done it this way because I am building a table that has a set number of rows but rather than horizontally scrolling all of the columns (the number of which are unknown since the user can add more) I need it to reach the edge of the screen and then create a blank row and then wrap to continue with the columns. I began by using one GridView and adding the header information on the first column but I ran into all sorts of issues with extremely complicated code for figuring out where to put what data in my custom adapter and also the getCount() in my adapter to make sure the right number of cells was being created including the blank cells.

Now I have the two GridViews and everything is working exactly how I want it to be apart from the scrolling. I want the two GridViews to scroll together (or as close to the same time as possible) when either is scrolled. Here is my code for the scrolling which is not working as expected:

```
     mRightGrid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            mLeftGrid.smoothScrollToPosition((firstVisibleItem / mRightGridColumns) + 1);  

        }
    });



     mLeftGrid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            mLeftGrid.smoothScrollToPosition((firstVisibleItem * mRightGridColumns) + 1);

        }
    });
```

Hopefully it is obvious that the intention of this is that if there are 10 columns in the right grid and that grid is scrolled so that position 30 (first cell of the third row) is the first visible item then the left grid should scroll to position 2 (30 / 10 - 1 = 2) which is the cell on the third row of the left grid view. So this doesn't work as I expected at all and I wonder if there is actually a way to evaluate the actual y position of the scroll every time that grid is moved at all and apply that same y position to the other grid which I believe would actually work and give good synchronized scrolling results.

Comment: You might be able to do this with some combination of `smoothScrollBy()` and `getScrollY()` and keeping track of the y scroll yourself whenever you get the onScroll callback. Honestly though, I think doing this with one GridView would be better. You could try extending GridView and have it display a view on top of the grid that displays the left column (the grid still has that first column, but if scrolled horizontally, the overlay will make it seem like the left column never moves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up biting the bullet and going back to one grid view and battling through the complicated code since no matter what I tried with the scrolling there was always a lag before the other grid caught up and I just couldn't find a way to smoothly scroll both grid views at the same time.